# Space efficient file type to store double precision floats

Tags: python, c, numerical-methods

I am currently running Simulations written in C later analyzing the results using Python scripts.
ATM the C Programm is writing the results (lots of double values) in a text file which is slowly but surely eating a lot of disc space.

Is there a file format which is more space efficient to store lots of numeric values?
At best but not necessarily it should fulfill the following requirements

1. Values can be appended continuously such that not all values have to be in memory at once.
2. The file is more or less easily readable using Python.

I feel like this should be a really common question, but looking for an answer I only found descriptions of various data types within C.

Comment: A raw binary file. Each double is fixed 8 bytes length.

Comment: `file format`, all files are binary. File format is not important.

Comment: Somehow I was under the impression, that I would need to know the number of values I want to write in advance, when using a binary file. But now that I think of it I do not see why I was under such impression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary file, but please, be careful with the format of data that you are saving. If possible, reduce the width of each variable that you are using. For example, do you need to save decimal or float, or you can have just 16 or 32 bit integer?
Further, yes, you may apply some of the compression scheme to compress the data before saving, and decompress it after reading, but that requires much more work, and it is probably an overkill for what you are doing.